# Can I use an Raspberry Pi 3 to mine Ethereum or is it useless?

Tags: go-ethereum, raspberry-pi, ethraspbian

I bought my Raspberry Pi 3 to run little Go based programming projects on it I stumbled over [Go Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)

After I watched some Youtube videos about Ethereum I wonder how much Euros can a Raspberry Pi 3 mine in a month max and is it even worth with the power costs ?

Comment: It is not worth the power costs.

Comment: That was what I suspected... it seems you only have a chance with this cryptocurrency is only worth If you pay nothing for the power and get in early

Comment: He said 10 H/s not 10 MH/s. On my GTX 1060 I get 20 MH/s

Answer (score 3):

You can get about [10H/s on a Raspberry Pi](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3hp1jc/how_many_raspberry_pi_nodes_make_it_1_ghs/) (some variant), so maybe 100H/s on a Pi 3 (generously). At current difficulty and prices, you'd make one US dollar in 125 000 days (about three and a half centuries). You'd probably be consuming about 5 watts (after factoring in power supply efficiency and excluding power to connect to network). A decent rule of thumb for North America is that a watt, consumed continuously for a year, costs about a dollar.

Answer (score 0):

On top of lungj's answer, 
do note that while mining on such a small output machine isn't worth it, you might as well look into setting it up as a staking node for a cryptocurrency that is currently Proof of Stake based instead of Proof of Work. That way you can actually leverage the minuscule power consumption of the Pi to your advantage.
 Also, do note that Ethereum is supposed to transit to PoS from PoW sooner than later as well.

Answer (score -1):

Im not quit sure: Just check out the online calculator for https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/

In fact it says: 36 Dollar profit per month, with 10MH/s, at 5 Watt for 1 Dollar per kWh.

So to me it does not sound impossible. In case you have to differ between bitcoin and etherum. Etherum mining is IMHO more RAM oriented and can not be optimized this strong with ASICs like Bitcoin, which IMHO could lead to this benefits.

Please comment

Comment: You re not going to get 10MH/s from a raspberry pi though. See lungj's answer.